# How to repeat a command in command-line mode

Tags: command-line, repeated-commands, vscode

I need to repeat the delete of matching lines in vscode-vim. Unfortunately the `g` has not been implemented yet, so I'm trying to figure out a way to repeat the same change in command-line mode using repetitions.

The following

```
20/pattern/d
```

will print a `Traling characters` error.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Are you saying that `:g/pattern/d` will not work in vscode-vim? Is that the command you're trying to execute that seems to not be implemented?

Comment: See also ["Neovim Integration"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim#neovim-integration) under vscode-vim readme. It seems to extend vscode-vim to support `:g`, `:normal`, etc.

Comment: You might also want to look into `vscode-neovim` instead of `vscode-vim`, see this article which talks about it and explores the differences between them: https://galenwong.github.io/blog/2021-03-22-vscode-neovim-vs-vscodevim/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running a command `:/pattern/delete`, the `:` register can be used to re-run the command like `@:`, which also takes a count (so `999@:` works). After the first use of `@:`, you can use `@@` (unless you execute another register in between, since `@@` always uses the last-executed register). With high counts this can simulate the effect of `:global` and more besides.